# In object oriented languages, when should objects do operations on themselves and when should operations be done on objects?

Tags: object-oriented, php, language-agnostic

Suppose there is a `Page` class, which represents a set of instructions to a page renderer. And Suppose there is a `Renderer` class that knows how to render a page on screen.  It is possible to structure code in two different ways:

```
/*
 * 1) Page Uses Renderer internally,
 * or receives it explicitly
 */
$page->renderMe(); 
$page->renderMe($renderer); 

/*
 * 2) Page is passed to Renderer
 */
$renderer->renderPage($page);
```

What are the pros and cons of each approach?  When will one be better?  When will the other be better?

---

**BACKGROUND**

To add a little bit more background - I am finding myself using both approaches in the same code.  I am using a 3rd party PDF library called `TCPDF`. Somewhere in my code I *have* to have the following for PDF rendering to work:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$html = "some text";
$pdf->writeHTML($html);
```

Say I wish to create a representation of the page.  I could create a template that holds instructions to render a PDF page snippet like so:

```
/*
 * A representation of the PDF page snippet:
 * a template directing how to render a specific PDF page snippet
 */
class PageSnippet
{    
    function runTemplate(TCPDF $pdf, array $data = null): void
    {
        $pdf->writeHTML($data['html']);
    }
}

/* To be used like so */
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$data['html'] = "some text";
$snippet = new PageSnippet();
$snippet->runTemplate($pdf, $data);
```

1) Notice here that  `$snippet` *runs itself*, as in my first code example.  It also needs to know and be familiar with the `$pdf`, and with any `$data` for it to work.

But, I can create a `PdfRenderer` class like so:

```
class PdfRenderer
{
    /**@var TCPDF */
    protected $pdf;

    function __construct(TCPDF $pdf)
    {
        $this->pdf = $pdf;
    }

    function runTemplate(PageSnippet $template, array $data = null): void
    {
        $template->runTemplate($this->pdf, $data);
    }
}
```

and then my code turns to this:

```
$renderer = new PdfRenderer(new TCPDF());
$renderer->runTemplate(new PageSnippet(), array('html' => 'some text'));
```

2) Here the `$renderer` receives the `PageSnippet` and any `$data` required for it to work.  This is similar to my second code example.

So, even though the renderer receives the page snippet, inside the renderer, the snippet still *runs itself*.  That is to say that both approaches are in play.  I am not sure if you can restrict your OO usage to only one or only the other.  Both might be required, even if you mask one by the other.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have wandered into the world of software "religious wars" here, along the lines of whether to use spaces or tabs, which brace style to use, etc. There is no "better" here, just strong opinions on both sides. Do an internet search of the benefits and disadvantages of both the rich and anaemic domain models and form your own opinion.

Comment: @DavidArno Use [spaces](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/15/developers-use-spaces-make-money-use-tabs/) you heathen! :)

Comment: Ha, I seriously don't understand this site at times. Perfectly good questions that get good answers are closed in no time as being opinion-based. Yet an obviously opinion-based question like this comes along and those usual suspects are nowhere to be found. Oh well, if you can't beat them and all that... :)

Comment: @Erik Eidt, could you undelete your answer please as I feel it as very good "forth option" answer.

Comment: the actual `$page->renderMe($renderer);` vs `$renderer->renderPage($page);` choice in many languages boils down to "who needs to do dynamic dispatch?", as **both** are *objects doing operations*

Comment: Don't you think the method `renderMe` of `$page` will have a code similar to `$renderer->renderPage($page);`?

Comment: Aside from SOLID principles, you may take a look at [GRASP](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~kena/classes/5448/f12/presentation-materials/rao.pdf), especially on *Expert* part. The question is which has the information for you to fulfill the responsibility?

Comment: I have added a more concrete code example, which suggests to me that both approaches have to be in play.  I am not certain that you can or should restrict yourself to any particular one, they may both be like different side of the same coin, as in both are necessary for code wiring to work.

Answer (score 13):

This depends entirely on [what you think OO is](http://wiki.c2.com/?NobodyAgreesOnWhatOoIs).

For OOP = SOLID, the operation should be part of the class if it is part of the Single Responsibility of the class.

For OO = virtual dispatch/polymorphism, the operation should be part of the object if it should be dispatched dynamically, i.e. if it is called through an interface.

For OO = encapsulation, the operation should be part of the class if it uses internal state that you don't want to expose.

For OO = “I like fluent interfaces”, the question is which variant reads more naturally.

For OO = modelling real-world entities, which real-world entity performs this operation?

---

All of those viewpoints are usually wrong in isolation. But sometimes one or more of these perspectives are helpful at arriving at a design decision.

E.g. using the polymorphism viewpoint: If you have different rendering strategies (like different output formats, or different rendering engines), then `$renderer->render($page)` makes a lot of sense. But if you have different page types that should be rendered differently, `$page->render()` might be better. If the output depends on both the page type and the rendering strategy, you can do double dispatch through the visitor pattern.

Don't forget that in many languages, functions don't have to be methods. A simple function like `render($page)` if often a perfectly fine (and wonderfully simple) solution.

Comment: Er wait a minute. I can still get polymorphic rendering if the page holds a reference to the renderer but has no idea which renderer it holds. It just means the polymorphism is a little further down the rabbit hole. I also can pick and choose what to pass to the renderer. I don't have to pass the whole page.

Comment: @CandiedOrange That's a good point, but I would book your argument under the SRP: it would be the Page's capital-R Responsibility to decide how it is rendered, maybe using some kind of polymorphic rendering strategy.

Comment: I figured the `$renderer` was going to decide how to render. When the `$page` talks to the `$renderer` all it says is what to render. Not how. The `$page` has no idea how. That gets me into SRP trouble?

Comment: I really don't think we are disagreeing. I was trying to sort your first comment into the conceptual framework of this answer, but I may have used clumsy words. One thing you're reminding me of that I didn't mention in the answer: tell-don't-ask data flow is also a good heuristic.

Comment: Hmm ok. You're right. What I've been talking about would follow tell-don't-ask. Now correct me if I'm wrong. The other strategy, where the renderer takes a page reference, means the renderer would have to turn around and ask the page for stuff, using the pages getters.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Likely yes. But this doesn't matter if the page isn't a “real” object with behaviour, and just a collection of properties (struct/POJO/POCO/DTO/bean/whatever you want to call it). FWIW, I do something like that in my blog: `templates[page.template_name].render(page)`.

Answer (score 3):

[According to Alan Kay](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/~ram/pub/pub_jf47ht81Ht/doc_kay_oop_en), objects are self-sufficient, "adult" and responsible organisms. Adults do things, they are not operated upon. That is, financial transaction is responsible for [saving itself](https://medium.com/@wrong.about/you-dont-need-an-orm-7ef83bd1b37d), page is responsible for [rendering itself](http://www.yegor256.com/2016/04/05/printers-instead-of-getters.html), etc, etc. More concisely, encapsulation is the big thing in OOP. In particular, it manifests through the famous Tell don't ask principle (that @CandiedOrange likes to mention all the time :) ) and public reprobation of [getters and setters](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html).

In practice it results in objects possessing all necessary resources to do their job, like database facilities, rendering facilities, etc.

So considering your example, my OOP-version would look like the following:

```
class Page
{
    private $data;
    private $renderer;

    public function __construct(ICanRender $renderer, $data)
    {
        $this->renderer = $renderer;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->renderer->render($this->data);
    }
}
```

In case you're interested, David West talks about the original OOP principles in his book, [Object Thinking](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735619654).

Comment: To put it bluntly, who cares what someone said about something to do with software development, 15 years ago, except due to historical interest?

Comment: The question is whether Page should message Renderer or the other way around. Saying objects are adults does not really answer this question either way.

Comment: @DavidArno I do care what a man who invented the Object-oriented concept said about what object is.

Comment: @JacquesB I've made it pretty clearly through my whole answer and, in particular, my example who messages whom. Moreover, I explained why it should happen within an object. Didn't I?

Comment: "*I do care what a man who invented the Object-oriented concept said about what object is.*" Why? Beyond lulling you into using "appeal to authority" fallacies in your arguments, what possible bearing could the thoughts of the inventor of a term have upon the term's application 15 years later?

Comment: @Zapadlo: You do not present an argument why the message is from Page to Renderer and not the other way around. They are both object, and hence both adults, right?

Comment: @DavidArno
Appeal to authority fallacy can not be applied here. An authority apparently has a solid understanding of what he's talking about. When I solve a physical problem, would you blame me for appealing to Newton's First Law? *what possible bearing could the thoughts of the inventor of a term have upon the term's application 15 years later?* -- well, there is one: the concept of OOP was distorted over the years. So the set of concepts that in your opinion represents OOP, is actually wrong. It has a right to exist, but don't call it OOP.

Comment: @JacquesB it depends on your domain. I imply that the page concept represent something real in OP's concept. And the renderer is a resource, that is a page's implementation detail. Makes sense?

Comment: "*Appeal to authority fallacy can not be applied here*" ... "*So the set of concepts that in your opinion represents OOP, is actually wrong [because it's a distortion of the original definition]*". I take it you do not know what an appeal to authority fallacy is? Clue: you used one here. :)

Comment: Um, I'm pretty sure I do know, as well as I explained why it can not be applied to my saying.

Comment: @DavidArno An appeal to authority isn't necessarily a fallacy. In this case Alan Kay certainly is an authority on OOP, and you have provided no factual reason why decade-old thinking about OOP might have become out of date. Best practices have certainly shifted over the years, but I think OOP concepts are generally timeless. My answer only avoids this by pointing out differing viewpoints. E.g. you could argue that Kay got OOP entirely wrong and warped a wonderful idea from Nygaard & Dahl. Or that Kay got OOP wrong because it's really about dependency inversion, as discovered by Robert Martin.

Comment: @amon, "*the concept of OOP was distorted over the years*". In other words, its meaning has changed. That's why Alan Kay's original definition is out of date. The term means what the current users of the term choose it to mean. Insisting that only he can determine what the term means is a fallacy. Just like suggesting Robert Martin "discovered" dependency inversion is a fallacy. He made up a term to describe something in OO terms that had existed in FP for example for decades previously in the form of HOFs.

Comment: *In other words, its meaning has changed.* No, its meaning was distorted, not changed. And the original definition is still yet to be rediscovered. Getters and setters were perfectly fine 10 years ago, and during the last decade there are already quite a few posts about why it's wrong. *The term means what the current users of the term choose it to mean.* No, this term while having some ambiguity is not **that** ambiguous. One can not to choose what is OO and what is not. There are basic and fundamental concepts like cohesion and encapsulation that form OOP.

Comment: The solution I provided respects them.

Comment: @David Arno So, are all appeals to authority wrong?  Would you prefer "Appeal to my opinion?'  Everytime somebody cites an Uncle Bobism, will you complain about appeal to authority?  Zapadio provided a well respected source.  You can disagree, or cite conflicting sources, but repeatefly complaining that somebody had provided a citation is not constructive.

Comment: @user949300 an appeal to authority is a fallacy if it is a false authority. "The inventor of X said Y 15 years ago and anyone who disagrees what was said then is wrong" is using X as a false authority. Alan Kay's contributions to OO are of historic interest only. He hasn't remained involved in OO as it has evolved, to the extent that "fan boys" like Zapadlo have to elevate those original ideas to near-sacred texts status and accuse anyone who thinks up new ideas of "mutating" the message and being plain wrong. That's the fallacy.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is unequivocal. It is `$renderer->renderPage($page);` which is the correct implementation. To understand how we arrived at this conclusion, we need to understand encapsulation.

What is a page? It is a representation of a display which someone will consume. That "someone" could be human or bots. Note that the `Page` is a representation, and not the display itself. Does a representation exist without being represented? Is a page something without renderer? Answer is Yes, a representation can exist without being represented. To represent is a later stage.

What is a renderer without a page? Can a renderer render without a page? No. So a Renderer interface does need the `renderPage($page);` method.

What's wrong with `$page->renderMe($renderer);`?

It is the fact that `renderMe($renderer)` will still have to internally call `$renderer->renderPage($page);`. This violates [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) which states

> Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units

The `Page` class does not care whether there exists a `Renderer` in the universe. It only cares about being a representation of a page. So the class or interface `Renderer` should never be mentioned inside a `Page`.

---

### UPDATED ANSWER

If I got your question correct, the `PageSnippet` class should only be concerned with being a page snippet.

```
class PageSnippet
{    
    /** string */
    private $html;

    function __construct($data = ['html' => '']): void
    {
        $this->html = $data['html'];
    }

   public function getHtml()
   {
       return $this->html;
   }
}
```

`PdfRenderer` is concerned with rendering.

```
class PdfRenderer
{
    /**@var TCPDF */
    protected $pdf;

    function __construct(TCPDF $pdf = new TCPDF())
    {
        $this->pdf = $pdf;
    }

    function runTemplate(string $html): void
    {
        $this->pdf->writeHTML($html);
    }
}
```

#### Client usage

```
$renderer = new PdfRenderer();
$snippet = new PageSnippet(['html' => '<html />']);
$renderer->runTemplate($snippet->getHtml());
```

Couple of points to consider:

- Its bad practice to pass around `$data` as an associative array. It should be an instance of a class.
- The fact that page format is contained inside `html` property of the `$data` array is a details specific to your domain, and `PageSnippet` is aware of this details.

Comment: But, what if, in addition to Pages, you have Pictures, Articles, and Triptichs?  In your scheme, a Renderer would have to know about all of them.  That's a lot of of leakage. Just food for thought.

Comment: @user949300: Well if the Renderer needs to be able render pictures etc. then obviously it needs to know about them.

Comment: Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns by Kent Beck introduces the [Reversing Method](http://www.sicpers.info/2014/10/reversing-the-polarity-of-the-message-flow/) pattern, in which both of these are supported. The linked article shows that an object supports a `printOn:aStream` method, but all that it does is tell the stream to print the object.

The analogy with your answer is that there's no reason you couldn't have both a page that can be rendered to a renderer and a renderer that can render a page, with one implementation and a choice of convenient interfaces.

Comment: You are going to have to break/fudge SRP in any case, but if Renderer needs to know how to render many many different things, that really is "many many responsibility", and, if possible, to be avoided.

Comment: I like your answer but I am tempted to think that `Page` not being aware of $renderer is impossible. I added some code into my question, see `PageSnippet` class. It is effectively a page, but it cannot exist without making some kind of reference to the `$pdf`, which is in fact a 3rd party PDF renderer in this case.  .. However, I suppose though I could create such a `PageSnippet` class that only holds an array of text instructions to the PDF, and have some other class interpret those instructions.  That way I can avoid injecting `$pdf` into `PageSnippet`, at the expense of extra complexity

Comment: @Dennis see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

> `$page->renderMe();`

Here we have `page` being completely responsible for rendering itself. It may have been supplied with a render via a constructor, or it may have that functionality built in.

I'll ignore the first case (supplied with a render via a constructor) here, as it's pretty similar to passing it as a parameter. Instead I'll look at the pros and cons of the functionality being built in.

The pro is that it allows a very high level of encapsulation. The page need reveal nothing about its inner state directly. It only exposes it via a rendering of itself.

The con is that it breaks the single responsibility principle (SRP). We have a class that's responsible for encapsulating a page's state and is also hard-coded with rules on how to render itself and thus likely a whole range of other responsibilities as objects should "do things to themselves, not have things done to them by others".

> `$page->renderMe($renderer);`

Here, we are still requiring a page to be able to render itself, but we are supplying it with a helper object that can do the actual rendering. Two scenarios can arise here:

1. The page simply needs to know the rendering rules (which methods to call in which order) in order to create that render. Encapsulation is preserved, but the SRP is still broken as the page still has to oversee the rendering process, or
2. The page just calls one method on the renderer object, passing its details in. We are getting closer to respecting the SRP, but we have now weakened encapsulation.

> `$renderer->renderPage($page);`

Here, we have fully respected the SRP. The page object is responsible for holding information on a page and the renderer is responsible for rendering that page. However, we have now completely weakened the encapsulation of the page object as it needs to make its whole state, public.

Also, we have created a new problem: the renderer is now tightly coupled to the page class. What happens when we want to render something different to a page?

Which is best? None of them. They all have their flaws.

Comment: Disagree that V3 respects SRP.  Renderer has at least 2 reasons to change: if Page changes, or if the way you render it changes.  And a third, which you do cover, if Renderer needs to render objects other than Pages.  Otherwise, nice analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you want as few dependencies between classes as possible, since it reduces complexity. A class should only have a dependency to another class if it really needs it.

You state `Page` contains "a set of instructions to a page renderer". I imagine something like this:

```
renderer.renderLine(x, y, w, h, Color.Black)
renderer.renderText(a, b, Font.Helvetica, Color.Black, "bla bla...")
etc...
```

So it would be `$page->renderMe($renderer)`, since the Page *needs* a reference to renderer.

But alternatively rendering instructions could also be expressed as a data structure rather than direct calls, eg.

```
[
  Line(x, y, w, h, Color.Black), 
  Text(a, b, Font.Helvetica, Color.Black, "bla bla...")
]
```

In this case the actual Renderer would get this data structure from the Page and process it by execute the corresponding rendering instructions. With such an approach the dependencies would be reversed - the Page does not need to know about the Renderer, but the Renderer should be provided a Page which it can then render. So option two: `$renderer->renderPage($page);`

So which is best? The first approach is probably simplest to implement, while the second is much more flexible and powerful, so I guess it depends on your requirements.

If you cannot decide, or you think you might change approach in the future, you can hide the decision behind a layer of indirection, a function:

```
renderPage($page, $renderer)
```

The only approach I will not recommend is `$page->renderMe()` since it suggest a page can have only a single renderer. But what if you have a `ScreenRenderer` and add a `PrintRenderer`? The same page might be rendered by both.

Comment: In the context of EPUB or HTML, the concept of page doesn't exist without a renderer.

Comment: @mouviciel: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Surely you can have a HTML page without rendering it? E.g. the Google crawler process pages without rendering them.

Comment: There is a different notion of the word page: the result of a pagination process when an HTML page formatted to be printed, maybe that what is what @mouviciel had in mind. However, in this question a `page` is clearly an input to the renderer, not an output, to that notion clearly does not fit.

Answer (score 1):

The [D part of SOLID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) says

"Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on abstractions."

So, between Page and Renderer, which is more likely to be a stable abstraction, less likely to change, possibly representing an interface?  Contrariwise, which is the "detail"?

In my experience, the abstraction is usually the Renderer.  For example, it might a simple Stream or XML, very abstract and stable.  Or some fairly standard layout.  Your Page is more likely to be a custom business object, a "detail".  And you have other business objects to be rendered, such as "pictures", "reports", "charts" etc...  (Probably not a "tryptich" as in my comment)

But it obviously depends on your design.  Page could be abstract, for example the equivalent of an HTML `<article>` tag with standard subparts.  And you have lots of different custom business reporting "renderers".  In that case, the Renderer should depend on the Page.

Answer (score 0):

I think most Classes can be split in either one of two categories:

- Classes containing data (mutable or immutable doesn't matter)

These are classes that have almost no dependencies on anything else.  They're typically part of your domain.  They should contain no logic or only logic that can be derived directly from its state.  An Employee class can have a function `isAdult` as that can be derived directly from its `birthDate` but not a function `hasBirthDay` as that requires external information (the current date).

- Classes that provide services

These types of classes operate on other classes containing data.  They are typically configured once and immutable (so they always perform the same kind of function).  These kinds of classes may however still provide a stateful short-lived helper instance to do more complex operations that require maintaining some state for a short period (like Builder classes).

**Your example**

In your example, `Page` would be a class containing data.  It should have functions to get this data and perhaps modify it if the class is supposed to be mutable.  Keep it dumb, so it can be used without a lot of dependencies.

Data, or in this case your `Page` could be represented in a multitude of ways.  It could be rendered as a webpage, written to disk, stored in a database, converted to JSON, whatever.  You donot want to add methods to such a class for each of these cases (and create dependencies on all kinds of other classes, even though your class is supposed to just contain data).

Your `Renderer` is a typical service type class.  It can operate on a certain set of data and return a result.  It doesn't have much state of its own, and what state it has is usually immutable, can be configured once and then re-used.

For example, you could have a `MobileRenderer` and a `StandardRenderer`, both implementations of the `Renderer` class but with different settings.

So as `Page` contains data and should be kept dumb, the cleanest solution in this case would be to pass the `Page` to a `Renderer`:

```
$renderer->renderPage($page)
```

Comment: Very procedural logic.